# SQL Table in Ascending Order + Get Last 50 Records

Tags: sql

Could anyone give me an idea how to fetch last 50 (or last n records ) when the table is in Ascending Order.?

Comment: Which dbms are you trying to achieve this on? Also, is there any code you have tried that did not work?

Comment: A table doesn't have an order, ever(!)... Order is determined by your query, and if none is supplied by PK, and i think indexes too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this post is old but had to share this solution.

I struggled with this for some time as well but at midnight today, it hit me like a rock. The below works for SQL Server and has a very fast return time. It returns the records in ASC order.

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE column1 in (
     SELECT TOP(50) column1 FROM Table1
     ORDER BY Column1 DESC)
ORDER BY Column1
```

note: changing `TOP(50)` to `TOP(5000)` on a 20 column table with approximately 300 000 rows, takes SQL Server 3 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

You can use - limit or TOP to solve it .

With limit -

```
SELECT  col1,col2,..  from table_name ORDER BY col_name DESC limit 50
```

with top -

```
SELECT TOP 50 col1,col2,.. from  table_name ORDER BY col_name DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**SQL Server:**

```
SELECT TOP 50 *
  FROM TableName
  ORDER BY ColName DESC
ORDER BY ColName
```

**MySQL:**

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TableName
  ORDER BY ColName DESC
  LIMIT 50
```

If you want to order by the result in ascending order of `ColName` again (as it is in the table), you can use an outer query to change the `order by`. Like:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT TOP 50 *
  FROM TableName
  ORDER BY ColName DESC) T
ORDER BY ColName
```